# how to stop page refreshing on button click i am using update panel but it is not work

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, updatepanel

1. i am using from validation on form submit click

   ```
   <form id="form_Institute" class="form-horizontal"
   runat="server" onsubmit="submitForm();">
   ```
2. update panel

   ```
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
    runat="server" id="txtintName" placeholder="Enter Institute Name" />

   <asp:Button ID="btnSaveInstitute" class="btn blue"
     runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click"
    CausesValidation="false"></asp:Button>
   ```
3. java script for form validation form for all html controls i give one control example

   ```
   $("#form_Institute").validate({
           rules: {
               <%=txtintName.UniqueID %>:{
                   required:true,
               },
   });
   function submitForm(){

       if(validate){

           return false;
       }
       else  {
           //document.form.submit();
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: in your form "onsubmit"-attribute, add the word "return": onsubmit="return submitForm();"

Comment: Can you post your aspx page code part containing update panel?

Answer (score 0):

To make UpdatePanel work you need additionally to place ScriptManager on your page with the panel:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
```

Comment: thanks but i added this already only not insert in this question.